# Images can be received as input in Dialogflow Chatbot?

Tags: dialogflow-es

i have a Use Case where i need to receive image as input from user in dialogflow chatbot. This images is require to send in webhook request to rest end point as fulfillment. 
I couldn't find anything which resembles to my requirement and also not sure whether it is supported in dialogflow or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you paint a broader picture of the use case.  I am having trouble imagining the user experience you want to achieve.  How are you imaging the image should be attached by the user?  My immediate gut reaction is to store the image in GCS and somehow have the webhook relate the image file to the current conversation.

Comment: Hey...as of June 2021, can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialogflow cannot take an image as input and map it to an intent directly. However, what you can do is process that image and send some text to dialogflow which will trigger specific intent and then proceed to perform the desired action.

You need to have a bridge between your user agent and Dialogflow, which will handle all the text/image request. It will do all the pre-processing and then call Dialogflow.
In this way, you need to send message to the messenger user using it's API's and call dialogflow using API/SDK as well.

[image: flow]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there any way where i can have get image as request from the platform which is integrating dialogflow, such as facebook Messenger. If not could you suggest any platform which fulfill my requirement.

Comment: @AyushMaheshwari I have added details to the answer, please check.